# Exception safety of std::vector, instantiated with a scoped allocator

Tags: c++

Does std::vector guarantee strong exception safety upon push_back(or emplace_back), even when it is instantiated with a scoped allocator?
Look at the following code,

```
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource r1{ 100 };
std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource r2{ 100 };
std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::vector<int>> v{ &r1 };
v.emplace_back(1);
v.emplace_back(1);
std::pmr::vector<int>* p{ v.data() };
std::destroy_at(p + 1);
std::construct_at(p + 1, &r2);
assert(v.get_allocator() != v[1].get_allocator());
v.emplace_back(); //safe of not?
```

vector would call allocator extended version of move or copy constructor when it needs to relocate the elements from current buffer to newly allocated buffer.
But because of the allocator miss-matching, exception may be thrown. In the case, if the vector has called move constructor, strong exception safety would not be guaranteed, otherwise the vector needs to copy the elements. Which is right?